# How to optimise wire gauge selection for electromagnetic applications?

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, solenoid, ampacity

**Disclaimer:** Hobbyist "maker" with limited experience and no relevant education. Please considerate and answer in detail. Feel free to skip to "Question".

### Context

I have an intention to build a simple solenoid for no other reason but my own interest. A basic review of theory brought me to the equation `B = μIN/L` whereby `B = Field Strength`,`μ = Magnetic Permeability`, `I = Current`, `N = Coil Turns` and `L = Coil Length`. For what ever reason my first observation was that there was surely an optimisation to be solved in the selection of wire gauge since an increased wire cross-section would increase your available `Current Capacity (I)` but decrease the `Coil Turns (N)` along a constant length. I then stopped short of attempting any calculation since `I` being proportional to the cross section area of a wire (in terms of Ampacity) and `N` being a first order relation, it seemed logic that the *"bigger the wire the better, turns don't matter that much"*... this can't be right. What further confused me was to investigate the current draw of commercial BLDC motors, of whatever size, and note that their amperage was surely beyond what would usually be carried on the wire gauges used for stators. Something to do with the AC driving? I sit confused.

### Question

- What is the optimal design approach for selecting wire gauge for electromagnetic coils of a given length and diameter?
- What factors are most import to consider?
- Are there conventions or standards I should know about?

Comment: Limited f- range of  response  T=L/R , Bsat core,  eddy current losses, loop area, magnetic coupling (leakage inductance)  crosstalk, Litz Wire, air core vs high mu , high voltage insulation magnet wire, self-capacitance (resonance) winding patterns.   , there's a lot of topics

Comment: Why would you assume a constant *length*? More practically there might be a constant volume available for the copper. The drive voltage may be fixed (something like a relay). You may notice that DC relays of a given design tend to have the same coil size and power regardless of coil voltage.

Comment: Realize that you are making an electromagnet, it will be much more powerful if you close the loop. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet#Magnetic_circuit_%E2%80%93_the_constant_B_field_approximation Same with a plunger solenoid, you want a path outside the coil.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 I'd already assumed I was scratching the surface of something much more complex. Do you perhaps have any recommended resources? Books?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Yes, thank you, that's what I'd meant in effect by "lenght". Constraining a factor like drive voltage would be a helpful start.

Comment: Tear down some solenoids , relays and try to measure L, R to get some experience

Comment: It turns out that the volume for the copper is something that is determined fairly early on in the design process. The volume is always filled with turns of wire. If the wire is thick, there will be fewer turns. If the wire is thin there will be more turns. This holds true for transformers and motors. Note that solenoids are motors. If you want more inductance (higher voltage lower current) you use fine wire. If you want less inductance (lower voltage higher current) you use fatter wire. But you always fill the volume with copper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, the choice of wire gauge is not so important.  You can pretty much design the whole rest of the system, and then pick the wire gauge according to how you want to trade off voltage and current at any given power level (P=VI).

Let's say you start with some electromagnetic system that has a coil made of AWG 21 wire...

You might measure I amps at V volts around N turns, and you might measure the DC resistance of the coil as R.  The power lost to heat is I<sup>2</sup>R.  The flux is proportional to IN.

Keep all dimensions the same, but switch to AWG 24 or so (pretend it's *exactly* half the cross-sectional area),  Now:

- The number of turns in the coil can double to 2N, because the cross sectional area of the wire is halved.
- The DC resistance increases to 4R, because it's proportional to turns/area.
- The current required to achieve the same flux is halved to I/2, because I/2 * 2N = IN
- The voltage required to achieve that flux is doubled to 2V, because magnetic EMF is proportional to turns, and (I/2)*(4R) = 2IR.
- The input power stays exactly the same: 2V*I/2 = VI
- The power lost to heat stays exactly the same: (I/2)<sup>2</sup>*4R = I<sup>2</sup>R

So after changing the wire gauge, the capabilities and efficiency of the system are unchanged.  We've just changed its operating voltage and its operating current in inverse proportions.

The capabilities of the system depend on the *shape* of the coil and other components, the *current density* in the coil and the *material* that the coil is made of.  (heat losses are K * current_density * coil_volume, for some constant K that depends on the material)

Comment: Fantastic! This really clarified for me exactly my query so thank you very much for your time and detail.

Answer (score 6):

Number of turns and current are variables that depend upon design goals. However, there *is* an optimization to be had in terms of geometry. A "Brooks coil" is a coil with a square cross section and an inside radius of the same dimension as a side of the square cross section.
[image]
(from [www.circuits.dk](https://www.circuits.dk/calculator_multi_layer_aircore.htm))

The Brooks coil has the property of maximizing the magnetic flux for a given length of wire.

Answer (score 3):

There is no ‘optimum’ but rather a compromise. A smaller cross-section wire will allow more turns but have greater resistance - this means more temperature rise. Ultimately the limiting factor is the temperature the wire insulation fails at - you want to stay away from this as far as possible.

How long do you want this solenoid energized for? For short term low duty cycle use you could tolerate the temperature rise. For example I’m working with some 12V solenoids at the moment. They draw 20A and will get extremely hot if left energised for over a couple of minutes. They are intended to unlock a mechanism so this limitation is not an issue.

For the joy of experimentation, I’d suggest you chose 2 or three different wire diameters and wind three solenoids.  See what the outcome is and use this information to guide your next iteration.

Comment: All very useful constraints to consider, thank you for your time and explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I don't have enough time to write a detailed answer. However, I wanted to give you a few pieces of general advice.  First: you've stumbled onto one of the most difficult parameters to determine when designing a device that makes use of coils of wire wound around a metal in a confined space. In pretty much all cases, you want to get as much copper into that space as possible. Mathematicians around the world and throughout history have spent thousands of man hours trying to work out THE best way to solve what they often call "optimum shape packing". And, usually, the object being packed is kept the same size, which is not the case here. You need to optimize both packing AND size. It's a tough process that is often tackled using "brute force" --- trial and error of perhaps hundreds of different sizes and arragements. Don't be discouraged by it's surprising difficulty. Secondly, as you think about different coils designs in your device, it's helpful to focus on a "figure of merit" --- some particular way to measure the expected performance of a particular design. Some examples might be:

- total copper cross-sectional area (add together all the cross-sectional areas of each wrap of wire in your coil)
- The ratio of turns/resistance (you will want to maximize this ratio -- which is affected by the shape of the space that will hold the coil AND the wire shape as well (sometimes square wire is best for square spaces, for example).

The "figure of merit" you choose will guide you in finding the best set of design parameters.

However, be prepared for a difficult time -- but it can be a very fulfilling experience when you have found the best design !

Answer (score 1):

TL:DR -the more copper you use (weight, volume, cost), the more efficient will be the magnet.

As Matt's answer says, changing the turns and wire cross section merely allows the magnet to run at the same power and the same field, while changing the voltage and current ratio, ie the resistance of the magnet.

An easy thought experiment to confirm Matt's assertion is to consider the magnet is wound with two identical sets of windings of N turns and A area. Each winding will generate the same heat, and the same field. If you connect them in series, you have 2N turns of area A. If you connect them in parallel, you have N turns of area 2A. You have changed the voltage/current ratio, you have changed the turns and the wire size, but you still have the same total amount of copper, and the same magnet performance.

Comment: Slight generalization: The more you raise the conductance of the (infinite) volume surrounding the core, the more efficient the magnet will be. An alternative strategy to using more and more copper is superconductors.